# Draggable element on ctrl

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

How can I let an element be draggable only when <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is pressed?
I tried to read [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) but it looks like there is no such option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48q5z/2/) showing my solution:

```
var box_dragOps = { 
        start : box_start_drag,
        drag  : box_dragging,
        stop : box_stop_drag
    };

$('#box').draggable(box_dragOps);


function box_start_drag(e, ui) {
    if(!e.ctrlKey)
        return false;
}

function box_dragging(e,ui) {

}

function box_stop_drag(e, ui) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#draggable").draggable();
   $("#draggable").draggable("disable");
   $(window).keydown(function(e) {
       if(e.keyCode == 17) {
            $("#draggable").draggable("enable");
       }
   }).keyup(function(e){
       if(e.keyCode == 17) {
           $("#draggable").draggable("disable");
       }
   });
});
```

This will work. When you let go of control, you can't move it anymore.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1wjbnqm2/